# How do you append multiple keys to a value in a list?

Tags: python, list, append, key

It works, but how can I add multiple values to a key?
This is my code:

```
    for x in range(number_of_wall):
        wall = 1
        wall_area = input("What is the area of wall {}" .format(wall) + " in " + room_name + ": ")
        dimention.append([room_name, wall_area])
        wall = wall + 1    
    print(dimention)
```

And this is what it comes up with:

```
[['Lounge', '13'], ['Lounge', '13'], ['Lounge', '13'], ['Lounge', '13'], ['Bedroom', '14'], ['Bedroom', '14'], ['Bedroom', '14'], ['Bedroom', '14']]
```

How can I modify my code so it comes up with:

```
[['Lounge': '13', '13', '13', '13'], ['Bedroom': '14', '14', '14', '14']]
```

Or something along those lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use dictionary in place of list for `dimention`:

```
dimention = {}
for x in range(number_of_wall):
    wall = 1
    wall_area = input("What is the area of wall {}" .format(wall) + " in " + room_name + ": ")
    if room_name not in dimention:
        dimention[room_name] = [wall_area]
    else:
        dimention[room_name].append(wall_area)
    wall = wall + 1    
print(dimention)
```

In this case, check for `room_name` present in the `dimention` if not add `room_name` as key and assign first value of `wall_area`; otherwise append `wall_area` to the existing `room_name` list. 
   You can also use `set` instead of `dictionary`.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Just curious, but is it possible to use a list instead of a dictionary? If so, how?